# Efficiently finding an Array within an Array with an Array with a wildcard

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of array objects in the following form:

```
[[eventID, IP, timestamp], [eventID, IP, timestamp]... ]
```

Every so often I receive a new array object in the same format ([eventID, IP, timestamp]).

I need to check the main array for an existing object with the same eventID/IP pair (which is quite likely) without matching the timestamp.

Obviously I could iterate through the list checking first for eventID, then for IP but this seems... inelegant.
I could use indexOf but I'm not entirely sure of the syntax for a wildcard element in an array used to match elements in an array.

What would be the most efficient way to search the main array for an [eventID, IP, WILDCARD]?

Comment: Is this a search you would do only once, or many times?

Comment: Many times. The main array will grow when there is a new eventID/IP pair. When the eventID/IP pair exists, the timestamp will be updated.

Comment: Does it have to be an array, or can we propose a structure that will allow faster searches? Also, could you provide some example data?

Comment: I have considered using key:value pairs. I'd like the know out of curiosity how to do it but if you know an overall most efficient way then I would definitely rather use that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a two-level key/value structure for fast look-up. Traditionally one would do this with plain objects, but since ES6 it is advised to use `Map` objects for such dynamically growing structures.

You could for instance use an object that acts as a hash with 2 dimensions (eventId and IP), which exposes get and set methods, internally using nested `Map` objects:

```js
function EventHash() {
    var hash = new Map;
    
    this.set = function (eventId, IP, timestamp) {
        if (!hash.has(eventId)) hash.set(eventId, new Map);
        hash.get(eventId).set(IP, timestamp);
        return this;
    };
    this.get = function (eventId, IP) {
        if (hash.has(eventId)) return hash.get(eventId).get(IP);
    }
}

// Demo
var hash = new EventHash();

hash.set(1, '123.123.123.123', 11111);
hash.set(1, '555.555.555.555', 22222);
hash.set(2, '555.555.555.555', 33333);
console.log(hash.get(1, '123.123.123.123')); // 1111
hash.set(1, '123.123.123.123', 44444);
console.log(hash.get(1, '123.123.123.123')); // 4444
console.log(hash.get(5, '123.123.123.123')); // does not exist
console.log(hash.get(1, '')); // does not exist
```

Comment: And that took me all of 2 minutes to implement. Feels very lean as well. Great stuff, thank you!